# Пространственная сложность рекурсивного алгоритма обхода дерева

Tags: c#, алгоритм, рекурсия, сложность, space-complexity

[Есть задача](https://leetcode.com/problems/univalued-binary-tree/) - проверить, что в бинарном дереве все узлы имеют одинаковое значение.

И [есть эталонное решение](https://leetcode.com/problems/univalued-binary-tree/solution/) при помощи рекурсии:

```
class Solution {
    public bool IsUnivalTree(TreeNode root) {
        bool left_correct = root.left == null ||
                (root.val == root.left.val && IsUnivalTree(root.left));
        bool right_correct = root.right == null ||
                (root.val == root.right.val && IsUnivalTree(root.right));
        return left_correct && right_correct;
    }
}
```

Работает... Но есть у меня сомнения, что в статье правильно указана сложность:

> Time Complexity: O(N), where N is the number of nodes in the given tree.
>
> Space Complexity: O(H), where H is the height of the given tree.

Моё видение такое: пространственная сложность должна быть тоже O(N), так как в худшем случае все элементы могут быть выстроены друг под другом и нужно учитывать и такой случай.

Но я что-то сомневаюсь... Расчёт худшего кейса это уже не нотация О-большое?

Это правильная логика, если нет, то почему?

Comment: Если все элементы выстроены друг под другом, то N = H, пространственная сложность все ещё опирается на высоту дерева. То есть и так и так верно будет по идее.

Comment: Тут всё правильно. Пространственная сложность O(H), где H это высота дерева. Если дерево вырожденное, то H = N и тогда пространственная сложность ухудшится до O(N).

Comment: Я так понял, что в теории они говорят об O(H), так как о самом дереве ничего не известно. В общем случае мы можем сказать, что высота дерева будет в худшем случае равна количеству узлов, но для сбалансированных деревьев это будет неверно (точнее верно, но неточно). Просто предполагаю, что это может быть причиной, почему там обозначили `Space Complexity: O(H)`, хотя мне кажется вполне резонно предположить `Space Complexity: O(N)` если специфика дерева на входе не определена.

Answer (score 4):

Пусть `H(root)` высота дерева. Сколько места требуется для вычисления `IsUnivalTree`?
Потребное место обозначим как `S(root)`. `S(null)` примем за ноль.
Сам вызов `IsUnivalTree` требует единицу - данные одного вызова занимают константную память. Память для выполнения первого оператора есть `1 + S(root.left)`. Память для второго оператора `1 + S(root.right)`. Операторы выполняются последовательно, общая память есть `max(1 + S(root.left), 1 + S(root.right))`. Упрощаем `1 + max(S(root.left), S(root.right))`.

Индукция: база очевидна. Переход: если `S(root.left) <= H(root.left)` и `S(root.right) <= H(root.right)`, то `S(root) <= H(root)`. Это следует из `H(root) = 1 + max(H(root.left), H(root.right))`.

Что и требовалось доказать. Заметим что в доказательстве не используется `N` - размер дерева, только его высота `H`. То что между `N` и `H` тоже есть соотношение - дело второе.